# ON LOAD synchronization with ANGULAR JS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, onload-event

I'm learning directives with angular js. I'm trying a simple piece of code on purpose to display a spinner while loading big images.

It's nearly OK, but when I'm loading several images, I'm surprised that all ONLOADs are fired at once when all images have finished. 
I would like them to fire independently each time an image has finished.

I guess something should be specified about sync to get rid of that but what?

Here's the code.

```js
app.
directive(
  'imgPreload', [

    function() {

      function preload(scope, element) {

        element.on('load', function() {
          // Image loaded: make it visible
          element.removeClass('image-hide');
          // Delete spinner
          scope.spinner.remove();
        });

        scope.$watch('ngSrc', function() {
          // Make image invisible while loading
          element.addClass('image-hide');
          // Get spinner image from HTML page
          var preloadImage = angular.element(document.querySelector('#preload-image'))[0];
          // Create a new image to display instead of real image
          // and affect it spinner's src
          scope.spinner = new Image();
          scope.spinner.src = preloadImage.src;
          // Put spinner in DOM instead of (side to side) real image.
          // Parent image is DIV. It's just to know where to insert the spinner.
          element.parent().append(scope.spinner);
        });
      }

      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: preload
      };
    }
  ]
);
```

```css
.image-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Spinner image for preloader (image is hidden: just to get the src when needed) -->
<img id="preload-image" class="image-hide" src="spinner.gif" />

<!-- 2 images are loaded, a small and a big (use of div is explained on JS) -->
<div><img src="petite_image.jpg" img-preload/></div>
<div><img src="grosse_image.jpg" img-preload/></div>
```